# I cant get my destructor to work in my code

Tags: c++

Like i said in the title i cant get the destructor to work. The reason being is that in this program i am required to use a int* array with negative indices: I keep getting this error at random times while running also:  Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x009DF130.
heres the code that i believe involves the error:

```
private: int* run;
IntArray::IntArray(int a, int b)
{
    int c = b-a;
    run = new int [c] + a; //This is how i give it a negative indicie
    h = b;
    l = a;
}
IntArray::~IntArray()
{
    delete[]run;
}
string IntArray::setName(string sp)
{
    s = sp;
    return s;
}
void runSim() {
    IntArray b(-4, 6);
    for (int i = b.low(); i <= b.high(); i++)
    // low is the lowes bound high  is the highest
        b[i] = i * 10;
    b.setName("b"); //this is where it breaks and gives me that error
    wait();
}
```

Comment: The most likely immediate cause of the error you are currently seeing is that you run out of bounds in the for loop. The upper bound is defined as `i <= b.high()`, and I am pretty sure it should be `i < b.high()`. But I would look at some of the feedback in the answers and rewrite the code as suggested there.

Comment: Your member `run` does **not** contain a pointer to the array you created using `new`.

Comment: @Galik run is a private pointer form my header file

Comment: @Tony.v But you don't set `run` to the pointer returned by `new`, you add the value of variable `a` to it first.

Comment: This code is doing some not so nice things with poorly named variables. I would possibly step back and describe what you are trying to achieve. That way you may get more appropriate answers which can avoid the problem altogether.

Answer (score 4):

The only right way to do this is to define a custom `operator[]` on your class.  The code you have has numerous errors:

1. You access both `low` and `high`, that's `high-low+1` elements.  But you only allocate `high-low`.
2. If `p=new int[high-low+1]`, then `run=p+low;` and `run[low]` means `*(p + low + low)`.    This is the proximate cause of your crash -- you wrote way outside the array, trashing internal metadata, which made dynamic allocation fail for the next user, your string's assignment operator.
3. You should have subtracted `low` when computing `run`, so that `run[low]` would give `p[0]`, the first allocated element.  But this might calculate a pointer outside the array (when `low` is positive), which is undefined behavior.
4. You pass a pointer to `delete[]` that didn't come from array `new`.  You need to pass `p`, not `run`, to `delete[]`.
5. You have no attempt at exception safety.  Management of dynamic memory in C++ is an advanced topic, and the evidence shows that you are not ready to do it yet.  So use an existing smart pointer to manage your memory.

Here's a better version:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class ArbBoundArray
{
    int low;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> base;

public:
     ArbBoundArray(int l, int h) : low(l), base(new T[h-l+1]) {}
     T& operator[](int o) { return base[o-low]; }
     const T& operator[](int o) const { return base[o-low]; }
};
```

That's it.  Less code, works for any type not just `int`, and exception-safe.

You can add your special needs like a name or whatever on top of that basic concept.

Comment: TY for the feed back and yes i have a overloaded [] operator along with others but there not causing the error its still something about memory and i dont know why also my full code would be to long to post

Comment: @jogojapan: Yes I did.  I thought it, but my laptop doesn't have a working synaptic connection yet so I actually have to hit the keys.  Bummer.

Comment: @Tony.v: Are you still having memory problems after fixing all the things I pointed out?

Answer (score 3):

Your have a simple errors:

Do not pass a value to `delete []` you didn't get from `new []` (or already passed once).

You need to undo your pointer-arithmetic to get the right pointer.

Also, be aware that if you create a pointer which points outside the array using pointer-arithmetic, you have Undefined Behavior.

If that's not your actual code, beware of trying to allocate less than 1 element.

Comment: could you elaborate on this"Do not pass a value to delete [] you didn't get from new [] (or already passed once)."

Comment: Quite simply, you get a pointer-value from `new T[size]`. You have to pass the same pointer-value to `delete [] p`, not some different (though related) one. Thus, if you only safed it as `p+3`, you must undo that addition, so you have `(p+3)-3`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you add `a` (aka `l`) to `run` when you `new` it, you must subtract when you `delete` it:

```
delete[] (run - l);
```

Comment: This is only applicable to the case he has given, what if different values are given to `a` and `b`?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Are you confusing `1` and `l`?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode that is an `l` (the variable name) not a `1`. That is why you should never name a variable `l`.

Comment: My bad hahaha that was what I though, I was confused because it didn't equal 1 either :L

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: yeah, I considered writing a tirade about the wealth of single-character variable names here, but decide not to.  I'm glad it's not just me who finds `l` confusing!

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to be mean, but this is pretty bad code.

First of all, if `b - a` returns a number less than `0` you will probably get an `std::bad_alloc` and if `a` > `c` you will be stepping into *undefined behaviour* [scary] territory and will probably get a segfault if you try to use the pointer.

Seeing as though you try to `delete[]` the pointer that points to `new int[c] + a` you almost certainly will get a segfault.

You need to do `run -= a` before trying to `delete[]` it, the implementation will either store information about any `new` or `malloc` in the space before the pointer that you get given so that when you `delete` or `free` the memory it just has to run behind the pointer and get any information it needs or store the info in a hidden array somewhere that is indexed by the numerical representation of the pointer. But probably the first. Either way, you're screwed doing what you're doing.